# Is 5 MB enough for precise measurement?

Tags: javascript, php, upload, storage

I need to get the internet bandwidth of my website's users, download is simple, but my `POST_MAX_SIZE` for upload is `5MB`, and I currently can't change it.

Is 5 megabytes enough for precise measurement of upload speed?

Comment: Please keep users with mobile data plans in mind ;-) (1GB costs ~25$ where I live, or 260$ with roaming, so downloading 5MB without asking will eventually make a few users really angry)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But is 5MB enough for speed testing or not?

Comment: Bumping this question